# Read CSV Transpose pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset that looks as follows:

```
Name  : joe
Job   : Crazy Consultant
Hired : 4/12/2011 3:38:55 AM
Stats : crazy, bald head
Pay   : $5000 Monthly

Name  : Matt
Job   : Crazy Receptionist
Hired : 4/12/2014 3:38:55 PM
Stats : crazy, Lots of hair

Name  : Adam
Job   : Crazy Drinker
Hired : 4/12/2017 3:38:55 AM
Stats : crazy, unknown
Term  : 4/12/2017 3:38:55 PM
```

I read in and get the data as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"pathtomycsv.csv", encoding="UTF-16", delimiter='\s+:').transpose()
```

Output of above: (just as an example)

```
Name      Job                Hired                 Stats                Name      Job                Hired                 Stats
Joe       Crazy Consultant   4/12/2011 3:38:55 AM  crazy, bald head     Matt      Crazy Consultant   4/12/2011 3:38:55 AM  crazy, bald head
```

Ultimately, I would like to take my dataset from above, and transform it into a dataset like below by combining all headers together like below:

```
Name      Job                Hired                 Stats                Pay            Term
Joe       Crazy Consultant   4/12/2011 3:38:55 AM  crazy, bald head     $5000 Monthly  N/A
Matt      Crazy Receptionist 4/12/2014 3:38:55 PM  crazy, Lots of hair  N/A            N/A
Adam      Crazy Drinker      4/12/2017 3:38:55 AM  crazy, unknown       N/A            4/12/2017 3:38:55 PM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like so:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file_name',sep='\s+:\s+',header=None).pivot(columns=0, values=1)
df.index = [df.index, df.Name.notnull().cumsum() - 1]
df = df.stack().reset_index(name='val')
df = df.pivot(index='Name', columns=0, values='val')
df
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The problem arises because you have more colons in the date. Use `"\s+:\s+"` as the separator. (Yes, it can be a regex.)

The following code works for me to convert your file into the table you want. I assume that 'Name' is always the first row in a set.

```
df = pd.read_csv("yourfile", delimiter='\s+:\s+',header=None)
df = df.reset_index()
df['index'][df[0]!='Name'] = np.nan
df['index'] = df['index'].fillna(method='ffill').astype(int)
df.set_index(['index',0])[1].unstack().set_index('Name')
#0                    Hired                 Job            Pay  
#Name                                                            
#joe   4/12/2011 3:38:55 AM    Crazy Consultant  $5000 Monthly   
#Matt  4/12/2014 3:38:55 PM  Crazy Receptionist           None   
#Adam  4/12/2017 3:38:55 AM       Crazy Drinker           None
```

Comment: Updated based on your comment, This helped me get the dataset into a DF but am still working on transposition of my rows to column headers combined.

Comment: I added more ideas to the answer.

Comment: Attempted this method, failed I assume, due to my dataset having multiple headers. It is different for each name some can have 4 up to 7.

Comment: Resulted in a key error zero, also seen that the additional column term is missing from your example.

Comment: I did not show the whole output. The rest of the code works for me with your input data. Interesting problem.