# pandas: Read multiline CSV like input with different separators

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a list of git messages where a git commit can be followed by a list of changed files, insertations and deletions, such as the follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO 

data = '''\
f0a332fc65|User 1|2017-01-30 17:26:51|Merge branch 'dev' into master
877134c7be|User 1|2017-01-30 14:46:55|commitmsg 1
 1 file changed, 15 insertions(+)

557b90502d|User 1|2017-01-30 14:38:52|commitmsg 2
 10 files changed, 51 insertions(+), 56 deletions(-)

052788be45|User 2|2017-01-30 14:29:28|commitmsg 3
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), ???? )
```

Each change information is followed by an empty line as shown in the sample above. But not all commits are separated  by an empty line (see the first line which is a merge commit that does not have any change information on its own).

How would a transformation look like that yields the following DataFrame?

```
         sha1  author                 date                         message  \
0  f0a332fc65  User 1  2017-01-30 17:26:51  Merge branch 'dev' into master   
1  877134c7be  User 1  2017-01-30 14:46:55                     commitmsg 1   
2  557b90502d  User 1  2017-01-30 14:38:52                     commitmsg 2   
3  052788be45  User 2  2017-01-30 14:29:28                     commitmsg 3   

   changes  insertions  deletions  
0      NaN         NaN        NaN  
1      1.0        15.0        NaN  
2     10.0        51.0       56.0  
3      1.0         NaN        1.0
```

This question could be related to multi-line inputs as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42037460/read-csv-transpose-pandas), but is somewhat more complicated.

I have a [working solution](https://gist.github.com/dotcs/ea90eb3939ed8723c685a0ef6e045f73) that reads the file in python and essentially extracts the change information separately from rest and later merges the two DataFrames. I think it can be done faster without the need to read the file via python but only use pandas io methods.

Comment: It would be nice if you could demonstrate the solution you have, so we could see if it is possible to make it more efficient. And I believe you have to process the data before feeding it to a DataFrame anyway, seeing as how it is "inconsistent" (varying number of lines before every changes-line).

Comment: @hooy Thanks for your reply. I uploaded my code [here](https://gist.github.com/dotcs/ea90eb3939ed8723c685a0ef6e045f73). Note that in my own implementation merge commits are not shown because I focused only on commits that made changes to the code base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider walking down the text file conditionally checking for combinations of *change*, *insertion*, and *deletion*, saving to a temp list and appending to larger list used in a `pd.DataFrame()` call.

```
rows = []
item = []

for line in StringIO(data):
    if 'commitmsg' in line:
        item = line.replace('\n', '').split('|')

    elif 'changed' in line:
        chg = [int(i[:3].strip()) for i in line.replace('\n', '').split(',')]

        if 'insertion' in line and 'deletion' in line:
            item.extend(chg)                

        elif 'insertion' in line:                
            item.extend(chg + [0])                                

        elif  'deletion' in line:            
            item.extend([chg[0], 0, chg[1]])

        rows.append(item)                
        item = []

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['sha1', 'author', 'date', 'comment',
                                 'changes', 'insertions', 'deletions'])    
print(df)

#          sha1  author                 date      comment  changes  insertions  deletions
# 0  877134c7be  User 1  2017-01-30 14:46:55  commitmsg 1        1          15          0
# 1  557b90502d  User 1  2017-01-30 14:38:52  commitmsg 2       10          51         56
# 2  052788be45  User 2  2017-01-30 14:29:28  commitmsg 3        1           0          1
```

Comment: I like both of your approaches, yours and the one from @bunji. I decided to mark your answer as the correct one because it performs significantly faster. I got around 1ms for this solution and around 53ms for the other one. Thanks to both of you for sharing your ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way that allows you to read everything into pandas in one shot and then requires some post-processing to get the resulting dataframe in the format that you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# read the data with comma OR pipe as the column separator  
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep = ',|\|', header=None)

# extract the number of changes (from column 0) and insert into column 4 
df[4] = df[0].str.extract('(\d+) files? changed')

# extract the number of insertions (from column 1) and insert into column 5
df[5] = df[1].str.extract('(\d+) insertions?')

# extract the number of deletions (from column 1 or 2) and insert into column 6
df[6] = df[1].str.extract('(\d+) deletions?').fillna('') + df[2].str.extract('(\d+) deletions?').fillna('')

# replace empty strings with np.nan so they can be filled in later
df[6] = df[6].replace('', np.nan)

# make a mask of the rows you want to keep (in the end)
keep_mask = df[0].str.match('^\w+$')

# for the rows that contain change, insertion, deletion data only:
# replace NaN values with 0 
df[~ keep_mask] = df[~ keep_mask].fillna(0, axis=1)

# back fill any missing nan values (should only affect columns 4-6)
# this should fill the row above each change, insertion, etc. row 
# with the appropriate values
df.fillna(method = 'backfill', limit=1, inplace = True)

# drop the rows that contain change, insertion, etc. data only
df = df[keep_mask]

# replace any 0 values with np.nan
df.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)

# name the columns what you want
df.columns = ['sha1', 'author', 'date', 'message', 'changes', 'insertions', 'deletions']

print(df)

         sha1  author                 date                         message  \
0  f0a332fc65  User 1  2017-01-30 17:26:51  Merge branch 'dev' into master   
1  877134c7be  User 1  2017-01-30 14:46:55                     commitmsg 1   
3  557b90502d  User 1  2017-01-30 14:38:52                     commitmsg 2   
5  052788be45  User 2  2017-01-30 14:29:28                     commitmsg 3   

  changes insertions deletions  
0     NaN        NaN       NaN  
1       1         15       NaN  
3      10         51        56  
5       1        NaN         1
```